# SSO logout on session timeout

Tags: java, security, single-sign-on, wildfly-8, undertow

When http session is invalidated explicitly, the following security session listener is invoked: `SingleSignOnAuthenticationMechanism#SessionInvalidationListener`

A user gets new `JSESSIONIDSSO` cookie in a response. Everything works fine. But when Session is invalidated by timeout, in the session listener we don't invode code that makes user logout from SSO:

```
        @Override
        public void sessionDestroyed(Session session, HttpServerExchange exchange, SessionDestroyedReason reason) {
            String ssoId = (String) session.getAttribute(SSO_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE);
            if (ssoId != null) {
                try (SingleSignOn sso = manager.findSingleSignOn(ssoId)) {
                    if (sso != null) {
                        sso.remove(session);
                        if (reason == SessionDestroyedReason.INVALIDATED) {
                            for (Session associatedSession : sso) {
                                associatedSession.invalidate(null);
                                sso.remove(associatedSession);
                            }
                        }
                        // If there are no more associated sessions, remove the SSO altogether
                        if (!sso.iterator().hasNext()) {
                            manager.removeSingleSignOn(ssoId);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The question is, why it works by this way? Can I force undertow  invoke associatedSession.invalidate(null); and sso.remove(associatedSession); on http session timeout? Now when http session expires, user continue to use the old JSESSIONIDSSO and server does not offer to change it.

Comment: I have the same problem, I want to invalidate all sessions if a specific webapp session is invalidated. Is there a way to create a custom listener for that ?